# transmission delay in store and forward, what is L/W and how to compute tw

Tags: computer-networks

I don't understand some things in Store and Forward equation:
[image: S&F]

- D  -> Number of channels and switches pairs.
- tr -> Routing time.
- tw -> Transfer time in a channel.

What is the **L/W**?

And normally exercises provide me **tw** (time transfer in a link), but now I am doing an exercise in which tw is not provided. I think I should compute with the **speed** of the links and the data **size** transferred. But I don't know what should be the size for the data.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit the question to provide more context.  What don't you understand?  What do each of the variables mean?  You should define all notation in the question, so it is self-contained.  Presumably wherever you got the equation from will have defined each of those variables at some point before the equation, so your next step is to start reading backwards until you can find where each one was defined.  One further comment: Understanding concepts is usually more important; computer science is much more than just plugging numbers into formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You ask us what $L$ and $W$ are.  But we can't tell you.  Only you know where the formula came from (you haven't told us).  And only you have access to that book.  If the book is any good, it will have defined what $L$ and $W$ represent before using them, so look through the book.  If the book uses variables $L$ and $W$ without defining them, then I recommend you look for a better book.

Comment: I am not sure, but could be that L means the size of the packet without the head, and W the Bandwith in the channel? I am not sure because in the previous page it puts w and not W with capital letter.